# Changing the MIME type of a file

Tags: windows-7, mime-types, mime

I am up-loading a file called ABCTAP.ttl to a maven repository. Before that I want to find the MIME type of the file and change it to MIME type txt/ttl. I checked that in Linux bash script we can use file --MIME-type to get the MIME type. But is there any way this can be done in Windows 7 command line?

Comment: DOS? wich version, may i ask?

Comment: how do I check that, I ran cmd /k ver and it gave Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]. Does that help?

Comment: Yes is not DOS, is windows 7. So please correct in your question DOS with "Windows 7 command line".

Answer (score 1):

Use the **AppCmd.exe** command from the `%SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\` directory.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc725608(v=ws.10)#command-line):

> To add a MIME type, use the following syntax:
>
> ```
> appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+"[fileExtension='string',mimeType='string']"
> ```